# How to export multiple instances of a program as a JAR file?

Tags: java, jar, game-engine, executable, packaging

I've been working on a game engine for a while, I finally finished it and now I want to implement the ability to export a jar file after designing a game in it, but the only possible way I found was using `JarOutputStream` which can copy the class files from your jar directory to another jar, but that isn't what I want, I want to export the INSTANCE of my engine, not the generic code that was already in my class files. Is that possible?

What I'm thinking of doing is when I'm ready to export, I would export all the original class files and program an interpreter that would hard-code the project info into a loader-class.. So; the following questions arise:

- Is this a good way of doing things?
- Is there a better way to do it, If so; what is it? (I'm pretty sure there is!)
- How do commercial game engines export their project as an executable?

Thanks!

EDIT: To make it clear on how my engine stores data, it currently saves data in an external file containing all project data, such as assets, game objects, etc..

But I cannot use that as the main method of loading games, because that would make a game very easily moddable (Anyone can change the data file; changing the game, therefore using the engine without my approval)..

As for what I mean by the current instance; I just meant that the engine uses an object-oriented approach to create the game, there are no "hard-coded" values, so if I just copy the classes from my engine's jar, that would not run, it would just crash because it does not have a scene to run...

Comment: You say that someone "designs a game". Don't you output some sort of save file with the game's resources? I would think you'd package that along with your engine code into the jar. (And most commercial game engines use self-extracting executables that unpack to a directory layout on disk, with the main engine code in a directory and the developer-provided resources in others.)

Comment: What precisely do you mean by instance of your engine?

Comment: @TomášZíma & chrylis I have edited the original post to make it more clear, Thanks for your responses!

Comment: Trying to keep people from using your engine by modding is futile. Just don't worry about it.

Comment: Well, I'm afraid you chose a not very well suitable technology. It's very difficult to protect software written in Java from reverse engineering and/or modifications. There are some options what to do with that, but it's extremely difficult.